# Javascript replace to uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I replace all the vowels in uppercase, with less code?

```js
var str = "aaeeiioouu";
str=str.replace(/a/g, "A");
str=str.replace(/e/g, "E");
str=str.replace(/i/g, "I");
str=str.replace(/o/g, "O");
str=str.replace(/u/g, "U");
document.write(str);
```

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: And on the assumption of being home work. The clue I'll give is capture groups. I'm not doing it for you though.

Comment: @dfsq, it needs to do VOWELS only.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar you are right, this way it's more interesting

Comment: Try to utilize array.

Comment: It's not homework xD just wanted to know another way to do the toupsercase without being a baker. ty btw :)

Comment: Totally looks like homework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts the `function` as the second parameter, you can use that and return the uppercase result. Also you can modify your regex to accept all vowels. You can use `/[aeiou]/g`

```js
var str = "aaeeiioouu";
str=str.replace(/[aeiou]/g, (c) => {
   return c.toUpperCase();
});
console.log(str);
```

According to the replace docs:

> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the
>   function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The
>   function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement
>   string. (Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do not
>   apply in this case.) Note that the function will be invoked multiple
>   times for each full match to be replaced if the regular expression in
>   the first parameter is global.
>
> The `arguments` to the function are as follows:
>
> **Possible name : Supplied value**
>
> **match**       :  The matched substring. (Corresponds to $& above.)
>
> **p1, p2, ...**     :  The nth parenthesized submatch string, provided the
>   first argument to replace() was a RegExp object. (Corresponds to $1,
>   $2, etc. above.) For example, if /(\a+)(\b+)/, was given, p1 is the
>   match for \a+, and p2 for \b+.
>
> **offset**          :  The offset of the matched substring within the whole
>   string being examined. (For example, if the whole string was 'abcd',
>   and the matched substring was 'bc', then this argument will be 1.)
>
> **string**          :  The whole string being examined.

Answer (score 0):

While not nearly as efficient as the regex `.replace()` solution above, here's an alternative that iterates through each letter and capitalizes vowels.

```js
var str = "aaeeiioouuxyz";
    str = str.split('');
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
  if ("aeiou".indexOf(str[i]) > -1) str[i] = str[i].toUpperCase();

console.log(str.join(''));
```